How do I end all animations on their last frame?
I've been struggling to get this button to start all my animations at the same time. After a lot of trial and error, I managed to get it working. However, when I watched how it played out, my elements weren't aligned, and the animation didn't stop when I added 'animation-fill-mode: forwards'.
Struggles:

Align the image and loading text in the center and position the image above the loading text.

Make the button onclick trigger the image and loading text, starting all animations until you reach the chapter selection.

Resolve the annoying flickering of the chapter text.

Ensure everything stops at the last frame instead of stopping at the first.


Feel free to assist the worst coder on earth. <3
Alignment: I've tried various methods, including creating divs, using display flex and grids, employing position absolute, and every imaginable technique. However, whenever I manage to get one part working, it seems to make it worse at other parts of the code.
Animation: Despite trying almost everything I could find online and reaching out to teachers and chatbots, no one seems to have a solution. I experimented with 'animation-fill-mode: forwards,' but it didn't yield the desired results. Unfortunately, that's pretty much the extent of my knowledge on the matter, my brain is very tiny.
Chapter Text: I attempted to address the flickering issue when the chapter text fades in. Surprisingly, shortening the text to "Chap" instead of "Chapter" seemed to resolve the problem, first try. However, upon refreshing the page, the flickering returned, GRRRR.
Start Button: I haven't given this issue as much love as the other issues. I tried using a solid black image with a z-index of -5 and an animation that set "0% = z-index: -5," "99% = z-index: -5," and "100% = z-index: 3." This approach failed, I decided to "Get the milk".
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7kBien8OL0w <--- Menu music

HappyErotisk <---


function ani() {
//Get All
var erotic = document.getElementById("erotic");
var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
var chapter = document.getElementById("chapter");

//Start animation
triggerAnimation(erotic, 'spinner 10s linear');
triggerAnimation(loading, 'fadeout 10s linear');
triggerAnimation(chapter, 'fadein 10s linear');
}

function triggerAnimation(element, animation) {
element.style.animation = 'none';
element.offsetHeight;
element.style.animation = animation;
}
* {
    text-align: center
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-size: 200%;
    font-family: cursive;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
}

a:hover {
    color: gray;
}

div.middle {
    position: absolute;
    display: grid;
    margin: auto;
    animation-fill-mode:forwards;
    animation: fadein 10s;
    z-index: 2;
}


body {
    background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

h1 {
    color: darkred;
}

h2.fadeout {
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    margin: 10% auto;
    position: relative;
}
/* 
div {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
} */


div.divbox {
    margin: auto;
    width: 70%;
    aspect-ratio: 16/9;
    display: flex;
    border: 5px solid white;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    height: 70vh;
}

div.load {
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 20%;
}


div.divboxx {
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    margin-top: -20%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
}

#erotic {
    width: 80%;
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

img {
    aspect-ratio: 1/1;
    width: 100%;
}

.helix {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: auto;
}


@keyframes spinner {
    0% {transform: rotateY(0deg); opacity: 100%;}
    50% {transform: rotateY(-900deg); opacity: 100%;}
    75% {transform: rotateY(-1350deg); opacity: 0%;}
    100% {transform: rotateY(-1800deg); opacity: 0%;}
}



@keyframes fadeout {
    0% {opacity: 100%; left: auto; right: auto;}
    50% {opacity: 100%; left: auto; right: auto;}
    75% {opacity: 0%; left: auto; right: auto;}
    100% {opacity: 0%; left: 100%; right: auto;}
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% {opacity: 0%; left: 50%; right: 50%;}
    75% {opacity: 0%; left: 50%; right: 50%;}
    100% {opacity: 100%; left: 50%; right: 50%;}
}

button {
    margin: auto;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<audio id="sound1" src="menymusic.mp3" preload="auto"></audio>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('sound1').play(); ani();">Play</button>
  
    <div class="divbox">
        
        <div class="divboxx">
            <img id="erotic" src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/60/60" class="helix">    
        </div>
        <div class="load">
            <h2  id="loading" class="fadeout">Loading</h2>
        </div>
       
        <div id="chapter" class="middle">
                <a href="../Kapitel1/Index.html">Chapter 1</a>
                <a href="../Kapitel2/Index.html">Chapter 2</a>
                <a href="../Kapitel3/Index.html">Chapter 3</a>
        </div>  
    </div>

</body>
</html>




animation-fill-mode: forwards; after animation not before it
